# Comic in which Scrooge McDuck sells all his alarm-systems and defends himself using ammonia and a flashlight

Tags: story-identification, comics, scrooge-mcduck

This might sound strange but I'm looking for a comic in the Duck universe where Scrooge McDuck sells all his weapons and alarm-systems to other billionaires, in order to save money (duh), and afterwards has to defend himself using rather primitive methods against the Beagle Boys. I remember him using a flashlight and ammonia.

Details might be different or outright wrong since it's been a long time.

Any leads are appreciated.

Edit: Some more details I remember:

- I read the comic in German in one of the LTB (Lustige Taschenbücher) about 10 years ago.
- I think it's one of the newer stories or at least should have been one when I first read it.
- The story also featured John D. Rockerduck (or Klaas Klever in German).

Comment: Some more details could help people find what you are looking for. When did you read this comic? Was it in English or in a different language? Do you think it was a new story, or the reprint of an old one? Where there other secondary characters?

Comment: I added more details I remember.

Comment: These books are Europe only I believe.

Comment: The Lustige Taschenbücher seem to be exclusively German featuring mainly stories from out of European countries, apparently.